# Why is JavaScript's undefined object and not a keyword

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering why is JavaScript's **undefined** created as object ([W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp)) and not defined as a keyword? And, are there any advantages to create custom undefined object (overwriting default undefined)?

For me, it's little bit confusing - as I've read, I should use

```
if(myObject === 'undefined')
{ /* ... */ }
```

although I often use incorrect version with `=== undefined`). But this approach seems to me like I try to compare `myObject` with `String` though I'm trying to determine `myObject` state.

So, is it conceptual mistake or there was some valid reason to create it this way?

And last question: is using incorrect version potentially vulnerable? (by JS modification from browser or browser plugin)

Thanks for all responses.

Comment: Are you referring to typeof(myObject)? undefined is a valid type, try: a = undefined; typeof(a); a will be undefined as a type, its type will be "undefined"

Comment: You should use: `if(typeof myObject == 'undefined')`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property

Comment: what is wrong with if(myObject == undefined)

Comment: w3schools is better than it used to be, but it's still not preferred over various other sources like [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)

Comment: To be fair w3schools never claims it's an object. It's listed under "JavaScript Objects, Properties, and Methods," not sure why the OP picked "object" out of that list and not "property".

Comment: How stupid to downvote this question. This kind of knowledge seeking is exactly what Stack Overflow is for.

Comment: I think you are using the term "object" incorrectly here. You seem to be asking why `undefined` is a **variable** instead of a keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not an object; that's just an example of why even today w3schools is a poor resource.

The `undefined` "value" (it's problematic to call it a value as it's more like the *lack* of a value) is a marker indicating that something just isn't present. It's somewhat odd that it's distinct from `null`, but it is.

The way you're testing for `undefined` is incorrect. You should either compare directly to `undefined`:

```
if (something === undefined)
```

or compare by type:

```
if (typeof something === "undefined")
```

It's very often the case that you don't really care whether something is `undefined` or `null`, in which case you can safely do this:

```
if (something == null)
```

because `undefined` is treated as being the same as `null` in an `==` comparison. (If you're a believer in the "never use `==`" religion, then obviously you wouldn't do that.)

Answer (score 0):

In most recent JS implementations, undefined cannot be redefined (you could before). `undefined = object` will still return undefined. Previously you could redefine undefined however that could cause compatibility issues if another library/script ALSO redefined undefined OR if it expected undefined to really be undefined. It is(was) thus a "really bad idea" to redefine undefined.

To compare against undefined correctly you have to do `object === undefined` not `object == "undefined"`. "undefined" between the quotes is a String.

There are other ways (`typeof object == "undefined"`) since typeof returns a String; that solution is a bit more obtuse to read and easier to make a mistake in my personal opinion but compatible with older JS implementations.

You can do `object = undefined` to empty the variable, that's why it's there.